# in vba Compare 2 columns from sheet 1 with 2 columns in sheet 2 in single workbook

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I wanted to compare 2 columns(A,B) value from sheet1 with 2 columns(C,D), if they match then in in next column of sheet 1 cell value should be "Match" and if not then "Not match")

In sheet1(A column should equal to ==)sheet2(C column)

In sheet1(B column should equal to ==)sheet2(D column)

e.g 1

SHEET1                       SHEET2

A            B                  C           D            E

101       2000              101      2000     Match(All 4 values are same)

e.g 2

SHEET1                       SHEET2

A            B                  C           D            E

101       2000              201      2000    Not Match(A and C

e.g 3

SHEET1                       SHEET2

A            B                  C           D            E

101       2000              101      3000    Not Match

e.g 4

SHEET1                       SHEET2

A            B                  C           D            E

301       7000              101      3000    Not Match

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub macro()

   Dim i As Long, iLast As Long
   iLast = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   For i = 1 To iLast
       If Sheet1.Cells(i, "A") = Sheet2.Cells(i, "C") _
          And Sheet1.Cells(i, "B") = Sheet2.Cells(i, "D") Then
          Sheet1.Cells(i, "C") = "Matched"
       Else
          Sheet1.Cells(i, "C") = "Not Matched"
       End If

   Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this code buddy ,Can we show Row Number where its "Matched".